# Rearranging the non zero entries in a tensor into a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a NxNx5 array T that I would like to convert into a Rx5 array TT such that the following condition is satisfied (where R is the number of non-zero entries of the array T(:,:,1)):

If T(i,j,1) == 0 then we ignore. If T(i,j,1) != 0 then I would like a row of TT whose entry is

```
[T(i,j,1) T(i,j,2) T(i,j,3) T(i,j,4) T(i,j,5)]
```

Note that T(i,j,k) (k = 2,3,4,5) could be zero. For example,

If

```
T(3,2,1) = 3
```

then I would like a row of TT to be

```
[3 0 2 1 5].
```

Some notes:

The entries of TT are all integers.
The entries accent in order column wise. i.e the first column of TT(:,:,1) maybe

```
[1 2 0 0 3 4 0 0 0 5 6]'
```

then the next column

```
[7 8 0 0 0 0 0 9 10 11 12]'
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Consider the following array: `T(:,:,1)=[1 0 3;6 2 0;0 0 5];T(:,:,2)=[4 7 8;2 0 5;3 1 0];T(:,:,3)=[1 6 2;1 1 1;9 4 8]` . What is the expected output?

Comment: You say "I would like a row of TT to be [3 0 2 1 5]", but then say something about "order column wise" that potentially contradicts that. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
ind = find(T(:,:,1));
ind = bsxfun(@plus, ind(:), (0:size(T,3)-1)*size(T,1)*size(T,2));
result = T(ind);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
clear
rng(343)
N=7;
K=5;
T=randi([0,4],[N,N,K])
TT=reshape(T,[N*N,K])
TT(T(:,1)==0,:)=[] %delete rows with first col equal to 0
```